# Relative positioning of stack child using child center in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

A part of my layout shows an image with objects on top. The image and the objects are in a `Stack`. For the object position I know the relative coordinates of the object's center relative to the image. For example (0,0) means the object center should be on the top-left corner of the image, and (0.23,0.7) means "center at 23% of the width and 70% of the height". I know the object size but I don't know a priori what size will be allocated to the image.

I tried using `Align` for this but it doesn't use the object's center: for example `Align` with `Alignment(1,1)` puts the bottom-right point of the object on the bottom-right corner. I then tried adding a transform to translate the object's center to (0,0), but this only works for the bottom-right corner, for example the position is then wrong when aligning at the center with `Alignment(0,0)`.

I thought of using a `Positioned` widget, but I cannot know the image size in the `build` function.

How can I position my objects correctly? In the example below, how can I get the red circle centered on the bottom right corner of the green rectangle? (in a way that also works for other coordinates)

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: 1.5,
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment(1,
                              1), // Should put circle center on bottom-right corner
                          child: Container(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,
                            // transform: Matrix4.translationValues(50, 50, 0), // doesn't work except for bottom-right corner
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text('Bottom widget'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text('Right widget'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: pls, elaborate on how you want the layout of the widgets. adding an image of what you desire will also help.

Comment: tried `CustomMultiChildLayout`?

Comment: @pskink thanks that works! I'll write an answer.

Comment: @anmol.majhail I tried to clarify the question

Comment: good, i'm glad to hear it works ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution based on a `CustomMultichildLayout` as suggested by pskink:

```
enum _Slot {
  image,
  circle,
}

class MyDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  final FractionalOffset objectCenter;

  MyDelegate({@required this.objectCenter});

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    Size imageSize = Size.zero;
    Offset imagePos = Offset.zero;

    if (hasChild(_Slot.image)) {
      imageSize = layoutChild(_Slot.image, BoxConstraints.loose(size));

      // Center the image in the available space
      imagePos = (size - imageSize as Offset) * 0.5;
      positionChild(_Slot.image, imagePos);
    }

    if (hasChild(_Slot.circle)) {
      Size childSize = layoutChild(_Slot.circle, BoxConstraints());
      positionChild(
          _Slot.circle,
          imagePos +
              objectCenter.alongSize(imageSize) -
              childSize.center(Offset.zero));
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => false;
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Center(
                      child: CustomMultiChildLayout(
                        delegate:
                            MyDelegate(objectCenter: FractionalOffset(1, 1)),
                        children: [
                          LayoutId(
                            id: _Slot.image,
                            // Use AspectRatio to emulate an image
                            child: AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 1.5,
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          LayoutId(
                            id: _Slot.circle,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 100,
                              height: 100,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text('Bottom widget'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text('Right widget'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The offset passed to the delegate can be any relative coordinate. In the example above I pass (1,1) so the red circle is centered on the bottom-right corner:

[image]